# How to uninstall this default localhost website from my machine

Tags: windows, server, localhost

I installed a Microsoft Navision Demo Server on my machine recently for testing/research purposes. When trying to work on one of my websites I noticed that when I browse to http://localhost/ ; this welcome page is being shown, does anyone know how to remove it? I have removed all Sites in IIS Manager but that hasn't helped. When I browse to 127.0.0.1 I get to see my own website that I am working on though.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the sites from IIS Manager actually did do the trick. It was a matter of clearing the cached localhost website from my browser.